# SQL PIVOT using two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Report Table

```
Country   | Report Section|  Report Field    | Report Value
--------------------------------------------------------
India     | Section1      | No of Employees  | 100
India     | Section1      | No of Dept       | 5
India     | Section1      | No of Contractors| 10
India     | Section2      | Avg. Working Hrs | 8
India     | Section2      | Avg. Utilization | 80
India     | Section2      | Avg. Pay         | 200
China     | Section1      | No of Employees  | 110
China     | Section1      | No of Dept       | 4
China     | Section1      | No of Contractors| 1
China     | Section2      | Avg. Working Hrs | 10
China     | Section2      | Avg. Utilization | 90
China     | Section2      | Avg. Pay         | 100
```

Need output like without any aggregate function

```
 Report Section|  Report Field    | India  | China
--------------------------------------------------------
 Section1      | No of Employees  | 100    | 110
 Section1      | No of Dept       | 5      | 4
 Section1      | No of Contractors| 10     | 1
 Section2      | Avg. Working Hrs | 8      | 10
 Section2      | Avg. Utilization | 80     | 90
 Section2      | Avg. Pay         | 200    | 100
```

How can achieve this using sql server PIVOT functionality

Comment: Please add the appropriate database tag - i.e. SQL Server supports pivot, while a number of other databases do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use aggregate for `pivot`

```
select *
from Report as r
pivot(
    max(r.[Report Value])
    for r.Country in ([India], [China])
) as p
order by [Report Section]
```

you also can do this without `pivot` operator:

```
select
    r.[Report Section], r.[Report Field],
    max(case when r.Country = 'India' then r.[Report Value] end) as [India],
    max(case when r.Country = 'China' then r.[Report Value] end) as [China]
from Report as r
group by r.[Report Section], r.[Report Field]
order by [Report Section];
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdd2b/8)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi Roman Pekar, Thanks for the input. How can I keep first two columns Report Section and report field